# Azure DevOps-Linux webapp doesnt show up

Tags: web-applications, azure-devops

I've created a new web-app in [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure) portal and using `Azure DevOps pipeline`.

I've chosen WebApp 'Azure App Service Deploy' task to deploy. I've authorized my subscription and when I try to select the webapp, I dont see my Linux webapp that i newly created.

I tried creating a new windows webapp with a new service plan and I was able to see that in the list.

Am i missing something here?

[image: Click here for the image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I had to select "Linux Web App" from the drop down list from the webapp type.

[image: Here is the link to image]